# running matlab simulink on the arduino mega 2560

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

Im trying to run simulink model in 'External' mode on the ARDUINO MEGA 2560. I get the following error message :

The call to realtime_make_rtw_hook, during the after_make hook generated the following error:
    The build failed with the following message: "C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2014b/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc" -

Comment: Is this really the complete error message? Seems the message itself is missing.

Comment: my board is clone version and it works well with arduino ide software there is no communication problem. but I cannot use it with the simulink. I ll post the whole error message. it seems like communication error.

Comment: my final aim is to read arduino I2C bus with s-function in simulink. now I can do it using arduino own software. Firstly I tried to check the communication between matlab and arduino from command menu it works. but when ı tried it from simulink with even simple blocks it always give error/warnings as in the files I uploaded I couldnt get any data so far of course I faced same warnings with tons of errors with s-function. http://imageshack.com/a/img673/6712/rJztp8.jpg
http://imageshack.com/a/img673/2985/abJPWO.jpg

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img540/9717/Z8dNWb.jpg (I changed the configuration parameters but the result is same )